# UPDATE Stored Procedure not Updating

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, if-statement, while-loop, sql-update

I've got a SQL Server stored procedure that references a table in my database where users can manually update values for a `rent` field (`'Rent1'`). The procedure compares this rent value to a rent field in a different table (`'Rent2'`). If `Rent1` is different from `Rent2` the value for `Rent2` Is updated to the value of `Rent1`... or at least that's what is supposed to happen.

When I execute this stored procedure, it runs fine and I receive these output messages:

```
(1 row(s) affected)


(1 row(s) affected)
```

Which is the result i'd expect, because as a means of testing, I have changed two values to be different between `Rent1` and `Rent2`. But then when I query my updated table, the values remain unchanged.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE update_rent
AS
DECLARE @flag INT
SET @flag = (select COUNT(*) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent)

WHILE (@flag > 0)

BEGIN

IF (select min(rent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent) <>
   (select min(srent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent
    and rent in (select min(rent) from unit_rent
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent))

BEGIN

UPDATE unittype
SET srent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent)
WHERE unittype.hmy = (select min(hmy) from unittype left outer join unit_rent on unittype = scode where rent <> srent
        and rent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent))

SET @flag = @flag-1;

END 

END

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF 
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong or tell me why my output messages are lying to me? Or maybe a different approach I could take? I'd appreciate any form of help, Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Just tried a different approach, same results, just 3 more `(1 row(s) addected)` messages:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE update_rent
AS
DECLARE @tmprent TABLE (hmy INT, rent decimal(11,2));
DECLARE @flag INT
SET @flag = (select COUNT(*) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent)

INSERT INTO @tmprent (hmy, rent) values (1, 0.00);

WHILE (@flag > 0)

BEGIN

IF (select min(rent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent) <>
   (select min(srent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent
    and rent in (select min(rent) from unit_rent
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent))

BEGIN

UPDATE @tmprent
SET rent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent)
WHERE hmy = 1

UPDATE unittype
SET srent = (select rent from @tmprent where hmy = 1)
WHERE unittype.hmy = (select min(hmy) from unittype left outer join unit_rent on unittype = scode where rent <> srent
        and rent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent))

SET @flag = @flag-1;

END 

END
```

Comment: It would help if you always used aliases when you join tables.  From out here we haven't much idea of which columns come from which tables.

Comment: I could however consider that comarisons to fields that contain null values may not work well unless you handle the null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how much my answer could help anyone, but on the off chance it could, i'll include it here..

So my `unit_rent` table being referenced in my SP, was created by me and populated with data from my `unittype` table (also referenced in SP). When I populated `unit_rent` table, I grabbed all the rows from my `unittype` table. This is where I made my mistake. The `unittype` table contained multiple units associated with particular unit types, so whenever I'd update one row with my stored procedure, all the other units associated with that unit type would become `!=` to the amount of rent I changed. So I re-populated my `unit_rent` table with only distinct unit types and my problem was solved.

Pretty silly mistake, but I'd prefer not to leave it unanswered on the off chance it may help someone else.

@granadaCoder - Thanks, **Again** for your help. Second time you've helped me very thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

In the trouble fixing world:

Put a select statement before the Update, to see if anything matches

```
/*
UPDATE unittype
SET srent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent 
    left outer join unittype on unittype = scode 
    left outer join property on property.scode = unit_rent.pscode
    where rent <> srent)
*/
select * from unittype
WHERE unittype.hmy = (select min(hmy) from unittype left outer join unit_rent on unittype = scode where rent <> srent
        and rent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent))
```

OR

```
declare @myCountCheck
select @myCountCheck =
(select count(*)
from unittype
    WHERE unittype.hmy = (select min(hmy) from unittype left outer join unit_rent on unittype = scode where rent <> srent
            and rent = (select min(rent) from unit_rent left outer join unittype on unittype = scode where rent <> srent))
)

if (@myCountCheck < 1)
BEGIN
    print 'No Row Match !!!'
END
```

EDIT---------------------------------------

If you really want to see what is happening, then code up some "output" auditing......
That way you can capture what is happening in the INSERT/UPDATE statement

http://granadacoder.wordpress.com/2008/12/10/sqlserver20052008-output-clause-in-insertupdatedelete-statements/

Here is the sample code:

SqlServer2005/2008 // OUTPUT clause in INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements

These types of samples are all over the place on the web, but here is my original example for which I believe is better clarity.

Original Example(s) at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/sqltips/archive/2005/06/13/OUTPUT-clause.aspx

```
create table PrimaryHolderTable ( i int identity (1001,2) not null primary key, j int not null unique )
create table #OutputResultsHolder ( i int not null, j int not null)

insert into PrimaryHolderTable (j)
output inserted.i, inserted.j into #OutputResultsHolder
select top 10 o.object_id from sys.objects as o order by o.object_id desc –<< from sys.objects is there just to provide some rows


select * from #OutputResultsHolder
drop table #OutputResultsHolder, PrimaryHolderTable;

go



create table dbo.EmployeeTable ( EmpKey int identity(1001,2) ,  EmpAge int not null );
create table dbo.AuditTable ( EntityKey int not null default -1  ,  OldValue int null, NewValue int null , Tag varchar(64)  );

insert into dbo.EmployeeTable (EmpAge)
output inserted.EmpKey , null , inserted.EmpAge , ‘Employee Inserted’ into dbo.AuditTable ( EntityKey , OldValue , NewValue , Tag)
 values( 18 );

insert into dbo.EmployeeTable (EmpAge)
output inserted.EmpKey , null , inserted.EmpAge , ‘Employee Inserted’ into dbo.AuditTable ( EntityKey , OldValue , NewValue , Tag) 
 values( 20 );

insert into dbo.EmployeeTable (EmpAge)
output inserted.EmpKey , null , inserted.EmpAge , ‘Employee Inserted’ into dbo.AuditTable ( EntityKey , OldValue , NewValue , Tag) 
 values( 22 );


update dbo.EmployeeTable
   set EmpAge  = EmpAge + 1
output inserted.EmpKey , deleted.EmpAge, inserted.EmpAge , ‘Employee Updated’ into dbo.AuditTable ( EntityKey , OldValue , NewValue , Tag)
 where EmpAge <=20;

delete from dbo.EmployeeTable
output deleted.EmpKey , deleted.EmpAge, NULL , ‘Employee Deleted’  into dbo.AuditTable (EntityKey , OldValue , NewValue , Tag)
 where EmpAge > 0;–Test multi rows

select * from dbo.EmployeeTable;–<<will be empty at this point
select * from dbo.AuditTable;

drop table dbo.EmployeeTable, dbo.AuditTable;
go
```

Comment: Sorry. If anything matches what?

Comment: You're running an UPDATE with a WHERE clause.  Ok.  Well, something has to "match" from the WHERE clause or anything to be updated.  By putting a SELECT statement immediately before the UPDATE (and assuming no one else is accessing the same data at teh same moment) you'll see if there is anything to actually UPDATE.

Comment: I think I understand. If I run the query from my where clause I receive one result and it's the result I would expect. `hmy` is the tables primary key and so there's only one row per `hmy`. SO with this being the case, my update should work, or at least i'd think..