# Stored Procedure not updating database

Tags: stored-procedures

Issue:

The database is not updating but I'm unsure where it drops.

I've used numerous ones in the past but I can't see why this is not working. If I could see how to run an error test on the stored procedure I suspect that would help.

Tests:

I pass the variables to a label, after the stored procedure request in the .aspx code to check the values exist (left in code)

Change int to varchar in the stored procedure

Query:

How do I fix this and then how can I run tests to find the issues in the future

Stored Procedure:

```
USE [DATABASE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spChangeValue]    Script Date: 11/08/2015 12:02:13 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[spRiskRatingChange] 
@ActionID int,
@EmployeeID int,
@NewRating varchar(10)

AS

DECLARE @DateChanged AS nvarchar(max) 
SET @DateChanged = GETDATE()

DECLARE @OldRating AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @OldComments AS nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @EmployeeName AS nvarchar(max)

SET @OldRating = 
(
SELECT OverallRiskCategory FROM TblAsbestos WHERE ID = @ActionID 
)

SET @OldComments = 
(
SELECT Comments FROM TblAsbestos WHERE ID = @ActionID 
)

SET @EmployeeName = 
(
SELECT UserFirstName + ' ' + UserSurname FROM SystemUsers  WHERE ID = @EmployeeID  
)

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE TblAsbestos SET OverallRiskCategory = @NewRating, RiskCategory = @NewRating,  
Comments= ('Rating changed from ' + RTRIM(@OldRating) + ' to ' 
+ RTRIM(@NewRating) + 'By ' + @EmployeeName + ' on ' + @DateChanged + ' -- ' + @OldComments) 
 WHERE ID = @ActionID

END
```

Code in .aspx.vb

```
 Dim connection As SqlConnection
            Dim command As New SqlCommand
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            Dim ConnectionString1 As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("VINCI_SQL").ToString()
            connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString1)

            connection.Open()

            With command
                .Connection = connection
                .CommandText = "spRiskRatingChange" 'include audit names
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .Parameters.Clear()
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionID", Session("ActionID").ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeID", Session.Item("EmployeeID").ToString)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewRating", ddOverallRiskCategoryEdit.SelectedValue)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()


                lblErrorMessageRatings.Visible = True
                lblErrorMessageRatings.Text = "Action ID: " & Session("ActionID").ToString
                lblErrorMessageRatings.Text = lblErrorMessageRatings.Text & " EmployeeID: " & Session("EmployeeID").ToString
                lblErrorMessageRatings.Text = lblErrorMessageRatings.Text & " NewRating: " & ddOverallRiskCategoryEdit.SelectedValue
```

Read items such as:

[UPDATE Stored Procedure not Updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197916/update-stored-procedure-not-updating)

Comment: what happens if you run it directly in sql?

Comment: I added values as: @ActionID int = '11829',@EmployeeID int = '143',@NewRating varchar(10) = 'Test' but there was no change in the DB.

Comment: the only time you use `@NewRating` in your sproc is when building the comment -- is that intentional?

Comment: Edited, sadly not the fix, would be nice if it was!

Comment: Have you used the Stored Procedure debugger in Visual Studio SSDT or SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Are you in a transaction that gets rolled back?

Comment: Can you post the DDL for TblAsbestos table ? Are you sure the @ActionID is the ID in that table ?

Comment: Try hardcoding the actionID in the stored procedure rather than the code and see if it works

Comment: Okay so it's something to do with the actionID @jazza1000

Comment: @Dai any great tutorials on that, I'll look up as I'd like to debug better than I am now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActionID", Session("ActionID").ToString)
```

try

```
.Parameters.Add("@ActionId",SqlDbType.Int)
.Parameters("@ActionId").Value = CInt(Session("ActionId"))
```

I am assuming it is an int value you are passing

.Parameters.AddWithValue does an implicit type conversion and perhaps this is what is causing your problem

Comment: Thanks, I removed '(int)' as this caused an error before it ran. Is that okay to remove that part, works?!

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I am mixing my VB with c# - I think it is CInt() in VB

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that for the future!